# Before Submit function not firing in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

Hi I have a jqgrid edit functionality through format actions. Is it possible can I use the method beforeSubmit and perfrom the validation.

```
formatoptions: {
                        keys: true, // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
                        onEdit: function (rowid) {
                            //alert("in onEdit: rowid=" + rowid + "\nWe don't need return anything");
                        },
                        onSuccess: function (jqXHR) {
                            $('input[id*="gs_"]').val("");
                            $grid.setGridParam({ search: false, postData: { "filters": ""} ,datatype: 'json'}).trigger("reloadGrid");
                            // the function will be used as "succesfunc" parameter of editRow function
                            // (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow)
                            /*alert("in onSuccess used only for remote editing:" +
                                "\nresponseText=" + jqXHR.responseText +
                                "\n\nWe can verify the server response and return false in case of" +
                                " error response. return true confirm that the response is successful");
                            // we can verify the server response and interpret it do as an error
                            // in the case we should return false. In the case onError will be called
                            return true;*/
                        },
                        onError: function (rowid, jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            // the function will be used as "errorfunc" parameter of editRow function
                            // (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow)
                            // and saveRow function
                            // (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow)
                            /*alert("in onError used only for remote editing:" +
                                "\nresponseText=" + jqXHR.responseText +
                                "\nstatus=" + jqXHR.status +
                                "\nstatusText" + jqXHR.statusText +
                                "\n\nWe don't need return anything");*/
                        },
                        afterSave: function (rowid) {
                            //alert("in afterSave (Submit): rowid=" + rowid + "\nWe don't need return anything");
                        },
                        afterRestore: function (rowid) {
                            //alert("in afterRestore (Cancel): rowid=" + rowid + "\nWe don't need return anything");
                        },
                        delOptions: myDelOptions
                    }
    }       ],
```

The function is never getting fired. I wish to perfrom ajax request for validation purpose ,

Kidnly provide help and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `beforeSaveRow` in inline editing (if you don't use some old version of jqGrid). The callback can't be set inside of `formatoptions` of `formatter: "actions"`, but you can use `$.jgrid.inlineEdit` instead:

```js
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
    beforeSaveRow: function (options, rowid) {
        ...
        return true; // return false break submiting
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, If I had to send my row data to server, how wil I serialize the data so that I can send it to server to validate

Comment: @user2375298: Sorry, but I don't full understand what you want to do. I understood your question : why `beforeSubmit` not firing? My answer was you tried to use form editing callback `beforeSubmit` instead of `beforeSaveRow` which can be used in inline editing. The best way for validation is *another question*. I don't know your full scenario. I think that no additional step for server side validation is required at all. If server will find the input data incorrect it should just return the corresponding error message and some error HTTP code.

Comment: @user2375298: Inside of `errorfunc` (which corresponds to `onError` in case of usage `formatter: "actions"`) one can display the error message to the user. If you use `restoreAfterError: false` then the user can continue editing the the row and fix the input to make it valid. If you have some problem to set error status code in HTTP response you can use `successfunc` (`onSuccess`) wwhere you can analyse the *body* of the row saving response and return `[false, "error massage from the server body"]` to inform about the error.

Comment: @user2375298: I'm not spring developer, but searching shows that you can use `return new ResponseEntity<String>("some error message", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);` for reporting validation error and use `return new ResponseEntity<String>(json, HttpStatus.OK);` for the response without an error. You need to change the return type of your controller action to `ResponseEntity<String>` of cause.